# Why is ReadOnlyObservableCollection.CollectionChanged not public?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

Why is [`ReadOnlyObservableCollection.CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653378.aspx) protected and not public (as the corresponding [`ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) is)?

What is the use of a collection implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` if I can't access the `CollectionChanged` event?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you be expecting a read-only collection *to* change? Surely then it wouldn't be read only?

Comment: Counter-question: Why would I not expect an ObservableCollection to change? What's the use of observing it if nothing is going to change? Well the collection is most definitely going to change, but I have consumers which are only allowed to observe it. Looking but no touching...

Comment: You should expect to change of ObservableCollection, but not Read-Only one even if it is a wrapper for first one.

Comment: I recently came across this issue aswell. Basically ObservableCollection is not implementing the INotifyCollection changed event properly. Why is it that C# allows a class to restrict access interface events but not interface methods?

Comment: A good question, probably should ask in as a separate one.

Comment: C# allows explicit and implicit implementation of interfaces. There are several reasons for this, but a big one is in case of conflicting interface definitions (i.e. two interfaces that you implement define the same member but you want them to do two separate things). It can also be to hide details about your class, a common example being explicitly implementing `IDisposable`). http://blogs.msdn.com/mhop/archive/2006/12/12/implicit-and-explicit-interface-implementations.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28VS.71%29.aspx has more details

Comment: I have to put in my vote for this being total insanity.  Why in the world does ReadOnlyObservableCollection even exist if you can't subscribe to CollectionChanged events?  WTF is the point?  And to everybody who keeps saying that a read-only collection will never change, think reallllllly hard about what you're saying.

Comment: @MojoFilter create a `private ObservableCollection` and initialize the `public ReadOnlyObservableCollection` passing in the private ObservableCollection instance. Updating the private ObservableCollection will update the ReadOnlyObservableCollection.

Comment: "read only" does not mean "immutable" as some seem to think. It only means that code that can only see the collection through such a property is not allowed to change it. It can indeed be changed when code adds or removes members via the underlying collection. Readers should still be able to be notified that changes have occurred, even if they cannot change the collection themselves. They may still need to respond to changes themselves. I can think of no valid reason to restrict the CollectionChanged property as has been done in this case.

Comment: I don't really see any good reason ... i wish someone from microsoft could enlight us on the reason for that, maybe taking a look at the code ...
no... still don't get it http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/readonlyobservablecollection.cs,30c05b005349f687

Comment: Not only that, in a ReadOnly-Observable-Collection all I can do is to Read it. If I cannot Observe it to read it again, they are ruining all the fun of it... :-(

Comment: Browsing the .Net code of `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` you will find this: `event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged`. Explicit interface implementation of the event.

Comment: @workmad3 _"Out of curiosity, why would you be expecting a read-only collection to change"_ -- Greetings from the future.  _"[This class is a read-only wrapper around an ObservableCollection<T>. If changes are made to the underlying collection, the ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> reflects those changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668620(v=vs.110).aspx#Methods)"_

Answer (score 64):

Here's the solution: [CollectionChanged events on ReadOnlyObservableCollection](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/5327c7d4-ef16-49e6-a8c0-c33ce06f87a2)

You have to **cast** the collection to **INotifyCollectionChanged**.

Answer (score 20):

I've found a way for you of how to do this:

```
ObservableCollection<string> obsCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
INotifyCollectionChanged collection = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>(obsCollection);
collection.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(collection_CollectionChanged);
```

You just need to refer to your collection explicitly by *INotifyCollectionChanged* interface.

Comment: Please not that ReadOnlyObservableCollection is a wrapper around an ObservableCollection - which is going to change. Consumers of the ReadOnlyObservableCollection are only allowed to observe these changes, not change anything themselves.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on this fact, read-only collection are not going to change in any case, cos it is called "read-only". This is my understanding.

Comment: +1 for the casting solution. But as for it not being logical to observe a read-only collection: If you had read only access to a database would you expect it to never change?

Comment: Agree, also what does it mean "Obsevarable" then in the name of the type =) Microsoft framework developers were drunk, probably =)

Comment: I don't see what the difficulty here is.  The ReadOnlyObservableCollection is a class that provides a READ-ONLY way to observe a collection.  If my class has a collection of, say, sessions, and I don't want people to be able to add or remove sessions from my collection, but still observe them, then ReadOnlyObservableCollection is the perfect vehicle for that.  The collection is read only to the users of my class, but I have a read/write copy for my own use.

Comment: Browsing the .Net code of `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` you will find this: `event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged`. Explicit interface implementation of the event.

Answer (score 8):

I know this post is old, however, people should take their time to understand the patterns used in .NET before commenting. A read only collection is a wrapper on an existing collection that prevents consumers from modifying it directly, look at `ReadOnlyCollection` and you will see that it is a wrapper on a `IList<T>` which may or may not be mutable. Immutable collections are a different matter and are covered by the new [immutable collections library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/09/25/immutable-collections-ready-for-prime-time.aspx)

In other words, read only is not the same as immutable!!!!

That aside, `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` should implicitly implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Comment: That's what the question is, so why not explicit implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`?

Answer (score 5):

You might vote for the bug entry on Microsoft Connect that describes this issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/641395/readonlyobservablecollection-t-collectionchanged-event-should-be-public

**Update:**

The Connect portal has been shutdown by Microsoft. So the link above does not work anymore.

My Win Application Framework (WAF) library provides a solution: [ReadOnlyObservableList](https://github.com/jbe2277/waf/blob/master/src/System.Waf/System.Waf/System.Waf.Core/Foundation/ReadOnlyObservableList.cs) class:

```
public class ReadOnlyObservableList<T> 
        : ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>, IReadOnlyObservableList<T>
{
    public ReadOnlyObservableList(ObservableCollection<T> list)
        : base(list)
    {
    }

    public new event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged
    {
        add { base.CollectionChanged += value; }
        remove { base.CollectionChanged -= value; }
    }

    public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add { base.PropertyChanged += value; }
        remove { base.PropertyChanged -= value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Connect has been retired. I would have totally voted

Answer (score 5):

There are definitely good reasons for wanting to subscribe to collection changed notifications on a **ReadOnlyObservableCollection**.  So, as an alternative to merely casting your collection as **INotifyCollectionChanged**, if you happen to be subclassing **ReadOnlyObservableCollection**, then the following provides a more syntactically convenient way to access the a **CollectionChanged** event:

```
    public class ReadOnlyObservableCollectionWithCollectionChangeNotifications<T> : ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>
{
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollectionWithCollectionChangeNotifications(ObservableCollection<T> list)
        : base(list)
    {
    }

    event System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged2
    {
        add { CollectionChanged += value; }
        remove { CollectionChanged -= value; }
    }
}
```

This has worked well for me before.

Answer (score 3):

As answered already, you have two options: you can either cast the `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>` to the interface `INotifyCollectionChanged` to access the explicitly implemented `CollectionChanged` event, or you can create your own wrapper class that does that once in the constructor and just hooks up the events of the wrapped `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>`.

Some additional insights into why this issue has not been fixed yet:

As you can see from [the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.ObjectModel/src/System/Collections/ObjectModel/ReadOnlyObservableCollection.cs), `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>` is a public, non-sealed (i. e. inheritable) class, where the events are marked `protected virtual`.

That is, there might be compiled programs with classes that are derived from `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>`, with overridden event definitions but `protected` visibility. Those programs would contain invalid code once the event's visiblity is changed to `public` in the base class, because it is not allowed to restrict the visibility of an event in derived classes.

So unfortunately, making `protected virtual` events `public` later on is a binary-breaking change, and hence it will not be done without very good reasoning, which I am afraid "I have to cast the object once to attach handlers" simply isn't.

Source: [GitHub comment by Nick Guerrera, August 19th, 2015](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/1029#issuecomment-132440625)

Comment: The actual problem, though, is that the class simply isn't fit for purpose. Maintaining a bug in the framework for the sake of some applications that "might" exist doesn't make sense. Especially when they can still wrap it to achieve protected status. If it's not going to be fixed, the class should be deprecated and replaced with one that actually performs as an observable collection. This kind of lazy approach to fixing issues with the framework is a complete cop-out and we shouldn't stand for it.

Comment: Well you can always cast an instance to access the event, so I wouldn't say it is unfit for the purpose. And let me remind you that binary breaking changes mean it will break at runtime. So changing it might mean that after a Windows Update that updated the .NET runtime, some software will suddenly crash the moment it tries to load the class (which might be some arbitrary point in time). I think preserving binary compatibility is a very reasonable goal. They could have changed it for .NET 6 though.

Answer (score 0):

This was top hit on google so I figured I'd add my solution in case other people look this up.

Using the information above (about needing to cast to **INotifyCollectionChanged**), I made two extension methods to register and unregister.

**My Solution** - Extension Methods

```
public static void RegisterCollectionChanged(this INotifyCollectionChanged collection, NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler)
{
    collection.CollectionChanged += handler;
}

public static void UnregisterCollectionChanged(this INotifyCollectionChanged collection, NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler)
{
    collection.CollectionChanged -= handler;
}
```

Example

*IThing.cs*

```
public interface IThing
{
    string Name { get; }
    ReadOnlyObservableCollection<int> Values { get; }
}
```

**Using the Extension Methods**

```
public void AddThing(IThing thing)
{
    //...
    thing.Values.RegisterCollectionChanged(this.HandleThingCollectionChanged);
}

public void RemoveThing(IThing thing)
{
    //...
    thing.Values.UnregisterCollectionChanged(this.HandleThingCollectionChanged);
}
```

**OP's Solution**

```
public void AddThing(IThing thing)
{
    //...
    INotifyCollectionChanged thingCollection = thing.Values;
    thingCollection.CollectionChanged += this.HandleThingCollectionChanged;
}

public void RemoveThing(IThing thing)
{
    //...
    INotifyCollectionChanged thingCollection = thing.Values;
    thingCollection.CollectionChanged -= this.HandleThingCollectionChanged;
}
```

**Alternative 2**

```
public void AddThing(IThing thing)
{
    //...
    (thing.Values as INotifyCollectionChanged).CollectionChanged += this.HandleThingCollectionChanged;
}

public void RemoveThing(IThing thing)
{
    //...
    (thing.Values as INotifyCollectionChanged).CollectionChanged -= this.HandleThingCollectionChanged;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## Solution

`ReadOnlyObservableCollection.CollectionChanged` is not exposed (for valid reasons outlined in other answers), so let's make our own wrapper class that exposes it:

```cs
/// <summary>A wrapped <see cref="ReadOnlyObservableCollection{T}"/> that exposes the internal <see cref="CollectionChanged"/>"/>.</summary>
public class ObservableReadOnlyCollection<T> : ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>
{
    public new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public ObservableReadOnlyCollection(ObservableCollection<T> list) : base(list) { /* nada */ }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args) => 
        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
}
```

## Explanation

People have asked why you would want to observe changes to a read-only collection, so I'll explain one of many valid situations; when the read-only collection wraps a private internal collection that can change.

Here's one such scenario:

Suppose you have a service that allows adding and removing items to an internal collection from outside the service.  Now suppose you want to expose the values of the collection but you don't want consumers to manipulate the collection directly; so you wrap the internal collection in a `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`.

> Note that in order to wrap the internal collection with `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` the internal collection is forced to derive from `ObservableCollection` by the constructor of `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`.

Now suppose you want to notify consumers of the service when the internal collection changes (and hence when the exposed `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` changes).  Rather than rolling your own implementation you just want to expose the `CollectionChanged` of the `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`.  Rather than forcing the consumer to make an assumption about the implementation of the `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`, you simply swap the `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` with this custom `ObservableReadOnlyCollection`, and you're done.

The `ObservableReadOnlyCollection` hides `ReadOnlyObservableCollection.CollectionChanged` with it's own, and simply passes on all the collection changed events to any attached event handler.

Comment: if by "for valid reasons outlined in other answers" you mean they made a mistake and can't fix it because it's a binary breaking fix.. then yea..  valid.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I meant.  I sympathise with Microsoft being unable to fix this, but at least we can create an isolated solution that gets us around it.