# How can I implement an interface member in protected?

Tags: c#, .net

I've been quite surprise when I saw the metadata of ReadOnlyObservableCollection in VS 2008...

```
public class ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> : ReadOnlyCollection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>
    //     class that serves as a wrapper for the specified System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   list:
    //     The collection to wrap.
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection(ObservableCollection<T> list);

    // Summary:
    //     Occurs when an item is added or removed.
    protected virtual event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Occurs when a property value changes.
    protected virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Summary:
    //     Raises the System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>.CollectionChanged
    //     event.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   args:
    //     The event data.
    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Raises the System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>.PropertyChanged
    //     event.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   args:
    //     The event data.
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args);
}
```

As you can see, CollectionChanged, a member of INotifyCollectionChanged is implemented in protected... and I can't do that in my own class.

.NET framework should not compile !

Does someone has an explanation of this mystery ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you closely examing ReadOnlyObservableCollection you will see that it **explicitly** implements INotifyPropertyChanged. In other words, the protected event handler is not the real implementation of the interface - [INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338311.aspx) is.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked with Reflector and here is what I found:

```
protected event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
protected event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged;
event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged;
```

So events actually are implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I am agree with **Mark Seemann's** answer and also take a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058176/why-is-readonlyobservablecollection-collectionchanged-not-public) some useful stuff can be found in answers. Its all due to explicit interface implementation. Try to implement *INotifyPropertyChanged* (or any other interface) explixetly in your type and then open it through Object Browser, you will see that is shows interface memeber even as private.